# Picture Number Operator in String Theory

Tags: string-theory, supersymmetry, conformal-field-theory, ghosts

My question concerns the ghost picture charge/picture number operator in the RNS formalism of Superstring theory.

In particular I refer to page 403 of "Basic Concepts of String Theory" by R. Blumenhagen, D. Lust, S. Theisen. They define this quantum number as
\begin{align}
N_p&=\oint\frac{dz}{2\pi i}(\xi\eta-\partial\phi)\\
&=\oint\frac{dz}{2\pi i}(\partial\chi-\partial\phi),
\end{align} 
where the super-conformal ghost $(\beta,\gamma)$ are bosonised by $\eta,\ \xi, \ \phi$ in the following way
\begin{align}
\beta=e^{-\phi}\partial\xi=e^{-\phi}e^\chi\partial\chi, \qquad \gamma=\eta e^\phi=e^{-\chi}e^{\phi}
\end{align}
I write here for completeness the OPE 
\begin{align}
\eta(z)\xi(w)\sim\frac{1}{z-w},\qquad \phi(z)\phi(w)\sim-\text{ln} (z-w)
\end{align}

My questions are the following:

1) How do you obtain the second step in the expression of $N_p$?

2) Since the action of the full ghost system ($bc$ and $\beta\gamma$) has a $U(1)$ symmetry, one can obtain a current $j_g=-bc-\beta\gamma$ from which one defines the ghost number $N_g=-\oint\frac{dz}{2\pi i}(bc+\beta\gamma)$. I expect the picture number to be related to the symmetry of some field. Is that so? Which symmetry produces this conserved number?

I write here, in case it is needed to answer the question, the action of the $bc/\beta\gamma$ system
\begin{align}
S_g=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int d^2z\ \  (b\bar\partial c+\beta\bar\partial\gamma).
\end{align}

Comment: It is very hard to answer this question without access to the book you are mentioning. (I suspect this number is (related to) the BRST charge, but there isn't enough information in the question for me to be sure) Please at least write down the action you're using and explain what all the variables are. Also, please only ask a single question per post.

Comment: I tried to add the information I could. This book doesn't write the action when one bosonises the ghosts, so this is what I could find. Regarding what you said: when you do the BRST quantization you do have a current associated to the BRST variation of the fields, but when you integrate that current you obtain the BRST charge. How can it yield another charge?